# Compute integral given 2 other integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to know which solution is correct.

The question states:

If f is an integrable function on [1,3], and if

$$\int_1^2f(x)dx=4 \space\space\space\space\space\space and \space\space\space\space \int_2^3f(x)dx=-1 $$

compute

$$\int_1^9 \frac{f(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}dx$$

My work:

The area under the function on [1,3] = 4 + (-1) = 3.

I attempt u - substitution:

$$u = \sqrt x \Rightarrow du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}dx$$

Since the function is now in terms of u, bounds must adapt

$$\sqrt 9 =3, \space \space \sqrt 1 = 1$$

$$\Rightarrow\int_1^3 \frac{f(u)}{u}\space 2\sqrt x\space du \space \space \space \space \Rightarrow \space \space \space \int_1^3\frac{f(u)}{u}\space 2u \space du$$

$$\Rightarrow 2\int_1^3 f(u)du $$

At this point I take my original sum from [1,3] and apply it, resulting in:

$$2*3.$$

However, the original function is in terms of x, not $\sqrt x$, so I don't know whether I should substitute u back in or leave as is.

Therefore, the answer is either

$$6 \space \space \space or \space \space \space 2\sqrt 3$$

or something completely different.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If $u=\sqrt x, \text du=\frac {\text dx}{2\sqrt x}$ then you have an extra factor $\frac 1{2u}$ in your calculations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already took care of the endpoints when you did the transformation.
No further substitution is needed.

$$ \int_1^9 \dfrac{f(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}\; dx = 2 \int_1^3 f(u)\; du = 
2 \left(\int_1^2 f(u)\; du + \int_2^3 f(u)\; du\right) = 6$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Sincerely.